# Calculating check sum of m-bus data frame

Tags: hex, protocol, binary-format, hexadecimal

I'm trying to calculate the check sum of a m-bus data frame. In page 1 of [this PDF](http://bg-etech.de/download/manual/SDM630-Mbus-protocol.pdf) I'm able to read that the frame's check sum "is calculated from the arithmetical sum of the data mentioned above, without taking carry digits into account". The data I have above are the bytes:

1. Start
2. L Field
3. L Field
4. Start
5. C Field
6. A Field
7. CI Field
8. Check sum
9. Stop

In page 2 we can find that one example of a valid data frame is:

```
68 03 03 68 53 01 BB 0F 16
```

In hexadecimal, being 0F the check sum. Unfortunately I must be doing something wrong because I'm not able to reach that value.

Could someone explain how this algorithm, to find the check sum, works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just one sample is never sufficient to answer a checksum query you need a bunch of samples to corelate and find patterns

so looking at the linked pdf it seems it is clear enough

skip the start and sum the data and extract the least two bytes

```
skip     sum     mask 
x,x,x,x | y,y,... 0x000000ff = checksum
```

so the sample you posted would be

```
skip         | sum            
68 , 3 ,3 68 | 53 , 01 , bb |  =
```

checksum

```
"{0:X2}" -f ((0x53+0x1+0xbb) -band 0x000000ff) = 0x0f seems to match
```

running this on other sequnces in the pdf seem to tally

```
PS C:\> $a = "{0:X2}" -f ((0x53+0xfe+0x51+0x01+0x7a+0x01) -band 0x000000ff) ; $a
1E 
PS C:\> $a = "{0:X2}" -f ((0x73+0x01+0x51+0x01+0x7A+0x02 ) -band 0x000000ff) ; $a
42
```